# Pass variable from 'list' to sqlcmd in .bat file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

This works in a batch-file:

```
sqlcmd -Q "exec sp_mysp @refdate = '2019-04-29'" -S myserver -d mydb -o C:\myfolder\result.csv
```

But I want the batch file to loop through a list of dates and pass each list member as variable to -Q instead of hard coding the date and the output file should also start with the date.

For a single date I have tried

```
set inputdate = '2019-04-29'
set "outputfile=C:\myfolder\%inputdate%_result.csv"
sqlcmd -Q "exec sp_mysp @refdate = try_cast(%inputdate% as date) " -S myserver -d mydb -o outputfile
```

But getting error: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'`

Removing the '%' around inputdate gives error message: `Incorrect syntax near 'inputdate'`

And using @inputdate gives error: `Incorrect syntax near '@inputdate'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `set`ting variables with values, you need to consider how it is interpreted by Windows `cmd`

Example:

```
set variable = value
```

This will be interpreted from the start of `variable` to the end of `value` So giving above example, you now have a variable of `%variable %` (note the trailing whitespace) and a value of `value` (note the leading whitespace). If you therefore attempt to `echo %variable%` it will return `%variable%` as the variable was never set, where `echo %variable %` would return a value, but still with the leading space which we do not want.

You therefore need to have no spaces between variable and `=` and no whitespace between `=` and the value. Additionally it is best to wrap your entire variable string in double quotes to ensure that you do not have trailing whitespace on the value, so finally, you would need to do:

```
 set "inputdate='2019-04-29'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would help:

```
IF exist inputfile.txt FOR /F "eol=# delims=" %%V IN (inputfile.txt) DO ( 
set "outputfile=C:\myfolder\%%V_result.csv"
sqlcmd -Q "exec sp_mysp @refdate = try_cast(%%V as date) " -S myserver -d mydb -o outputfile
)
```

This batch-command iterates through each date (one date per line) from the textfile.txt which is located in the same folder as your .bat file and executes your code for each entry.

Comment: Nope, this will never work.. Try it, setup a batch file as you have and do `echo %inputdate%` then you'll see.

Comment: Thanks for your Feedback Gerard. I think i fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may try to set batch variables like `set inputdate='2019-04-29'`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
set inputdate = '2019-04-29'
set "outputfile=C:\myfolder\%inputdate%_result.csv"
sqlcmd -Q "exec sp_mysp @refdate = try_cast($(inputdate) as date) " -S myserver -d mydb -o outputfile
```

I confirmed in a batch file like this:

```
set inputdate='2019-04-29'
sqlcmd -Q "print $(inputdate)" -S myserver -E
```

Comment: Yeah, the OP is talking about syntax "works in a batch-file".  And, yes, I confirmed it in "test.bat" at a Windows Command Prompt.  `$()` is how to read environment variables from inside a SQL script.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the double quotes to wrap the date in.
The Powershell equivalent would be:

```
# Dates
$dates = @(
    '2019-04-29'
)

$dates  | ForEach-Object {
    # Date
    $inputdate = $_
    # Command to run
    $cmd = "DECLARE @refdate as datetime; set @refdate = try_cast ('$inputdate' as date) ; exec sp_mysp @refdate " 

    $args = @( 
        '-Q'
        $cmd    
        '-S'
        'myserver'
        '-d'
        'mydb'
        '-o' 
        'outputfile'
    )
    Write-Host "Running : $cmd "
    & 'sqlcmd' $args
}
```